# Unable to access the table column values using d3.selectAll

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to add colour based on value (heatmap) to a table column but I ain't able to select the td.dc-table-column _4 to change its color. I tried everything but not working.

here is the working demo: https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/f442f5ccbf25eb853c7508194688d25d

Line no 144         `log("SSSSSSSSSS:",d3.selectAll('td.dc-table-column _4'));`  of `index.js`.

I am trying to put color on probabilities value which will be like this: http://bl.ocks.org/curran/3094b37e63b918bab0a06787e161607b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `renderlet`

I was able to do so.

```
.renderlet(function(chart){
    chart.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._4')
         .style("background-color", function(d){ 
          return color(d.predicted_probability)});
  });
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out! The `pretransition` [event](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#on__anchor) is slightly better for this purpose because there is no delay - `renderlet` is after transitions, `pretransition` before.